# How to check all the links dynamically?

Tags: dynamic, vbscript, qtp

The following thing I have to do using VBScript in QTP 10/11:

The VBScript opens one login page. After the login it counts the number of links in that page and then prints all the links. Afterwards it opens every link one by one.

I am having issues with finding all the dynamic links.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the links on a page by using the `Page`'s (or `Frame`'s) `ChildObject` method.

```
Set desc = Description.Create()
desc("html tag").Value = "a"
Set links = Browser("B").Page("P").ChildObjects(desc)
For i = 0 to links.Count - 1
    Print links(i).GetRoProperty("inner_text") & " => " & links(i).GetRoProperty("href")
Next
```

As for clicking them, that's a bit more complicated since after clicking a link you cause a navigation that invalidates the `links` object, you should either perform the `ChildObjects` each time (while keeping track of the index) or open the links in a different browser/tab.

Comment: Hi Moti Thanks for feedback, Do u let me know how I will use the childObjects each time approach

Comment: @ShwetaSingh call `ChildObjects` once to get the count, then use `ChildObjects` inside the `For` loop to get a new `links` object.

Comment: HI Moti, this is my code tell me how to use child object in this..              Dim oDesc        
Dim colObject   
Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc( "micclass" ).value = "Link"
'Additional property- for more focused and controlled collection
'oDesc( "text" ).value = "Images"
Set colObject = Browser( "micClass:=Browser").Page("micClass:=Page").ChildObjects( oDesc )
Msgbox colObject.Count    'Returns 1 
if colObject.count <>0 then
For i=3 to colObject.Count-1
tag=colObject(i).GetROProperty("name")
href=colObject(i).GetROProperty("url")
Msgbox tag
'Msgbox href
Next
End If